# map pipeline operator associated with function interface

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, mapping

I can't understand why the `String::toUpperCase()` expression works fine inside the Stream **`map` pipeline**. When I look at this example here:

```
Stream.of("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4")
                .filter(s -> s.contains("r"))
                .map(s -> s + "map")
                .map(String::toUpperCase)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

When I look to the definition of the map operator used in the example below `map(Function<? super String, ? extends String> mapper)` I saw a function design pattern is been used.

In this example `.map(s -> s + "map")` is fine, as I understand we are looking for Function more precisely the `R apply(T t);`, it is totally what the lambda expression said `s -> s + "map"` here we have a function with a parameter s and it returns s + String "map" and it conforms to this spec. `T` and `R`, they are present.

On the other side the second one `map(String::toUpperCase)`, I can't understand why the expression `toUpperCase` is considered as a `Function` interface, I should note the core of this function is like this

```
public String toUpperCase() {
    return toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
}
```

and we are looking for `R apply(T t);` there is no T parameter in this method `toUpperCase`? Why does this one work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's much easier to understand in terms of the `apply` method of the `Function` interface is the anonymous class representation of the method reference `String::toUpperCase`. It goes like this -

```
new Function<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(String str) { // read as given a String return a String (uppercased)
        return str.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

The string arguments(`str`) provided to the above `apply` method are the ones from the `Stream` after the previous `map` operation.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a method reference and it's syntactic sugar for a lambda expression. In other words the following:

```
String::toUpperCase
```

is equivalent to:

```
s -> s.toUpperCase()
```

It's a method that takes a `String` `s` and returns a `String` with all letter from `s` uppercase, it's a `Function<String, String>`.

Comment: the method must have the same signature as the functional interface```R apply(T t)``` with the lambdas s->s.toUpperCase() it is very clear for me, with String::toUpperCase i can't see the passed parameter, the signature definition is empty for this one and it return a String !!! can you explain me this point please

Comment: for example for this one .forEach(System.out::println);
 .forEach( s-> System.out.println(s)); i undrestand they are same , the method reference println, consumer look for the void accept(T t) method; and return void , the core definition of println is conforme public void println(String x), only one parameter and return void

Comment: @Feres.o you totally misunderstand this. What if I had a function `String f(String s, int i, double d, char c)` and call it like `s -> f(s, 1, 2.3, 'a')`? The function takes 4 parameters, but it does not matter, because **the lambda** only takes and returns one.

Comment: for me it is   ( s, i , d, c) -> { statements
then return a String }

Comment: @Feres.o other parameters of the inner function are fixed